# MD5 hash all files and then Compare with the Original csv

Tags: powershell

i want PowerShell after Creating MD5 Hashes for all of my Media files using the Command bellow

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Media 1\' -Recurse -File |  
       Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | 
       Export-Csv -Path 'D:\MediaHashes1.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

to Compare the new Created Mediahashes1.csv with the Original D"\Originalhashes.csv
and Create a new csv file notify me if they are identical or Not
thanks

Comment: Did you look at [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1)?

Comment: i want to Compare Every single hash Inside the newly created CSV and compare with the hashes inside the Originalhashes.csv and then Powershell for example to create a new CSV file telling me if they are identical or Not i will be more than happy if powershell can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Import-Csv` to read old CSV and new CSV into separate variables, then call [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1) to compare them. Make sure to compare on both `Hash` and `Path` to detect moved files.

```
$oldHashes = Import-Csv oldhashes.csv
$newHashes = Import-Csv newhashes.csv
Compare-Object $oldHashes $newHashes -Property Hash, Path | Export-Csv difference.csv
```

As a performance optimization, you could store the new hashes in a variable, while you are generating them. This way you wouldn't have to read the new hashes from the file back again.

The output file 'difference.csv' will be empty if CSVs are equal.

Otherwise the output file contains all differences. The column `SideIndicator` indicates whether a given combination of Hash and Path exists only in the `oldhashes.csv` (SideIndicator `<=`) or only in the `newhashes.csv` (SideIndicator `=>`).

---

#### Further improvements

The above code outputs duplicate paths, in case a file has been modified. Example output in table format for readability:

```text
Path            Hash                             SideIndicator
----            ----                             -------------
C:\test\bar.txt 73FEFFA4B7F6BB68E44CF984C85F6E88 <=
C:\test\baz.txt D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E =>
C:\test\foo.txt 2AF65102DB00B80835E1578278064AD1 =>
C:\test\foo.txt 37B51D194A7513E45B56F6524F2D51F2 <=
```

The file "foo.txt" is listed twice because it exists in old and new state but has modified content. To remove duplicate paths, we can use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1) to group on the `Path` property:

```
# Compare and store differences in variable $diff
$diff = Compare-Object $oldHashes $newHashes -Property Path, Hash | Sort-Object 

# Group on path to create only a single output item for each modified file
$groupedDiff = $diff | Group-Object Path | ForEach-Object {

    # The pscustomobject is the output of the ForEach-Object script block
    [pscustomobject] @{
        Path = $_.Name

        # If group has only one element, the file exists either in old or in new state.
        # Otherwise we have a modified file, which will be indicated by
        # special SideIndicator value '<>'.
        SideIndicator = if( $_.Count -eq 1 ) { $_.Group.SideIndicator } else { '<>' }
    }
}

$groupedDiff | Export-Csv difference.csv
```

Contents of `$groupedDiff` in table format:

```text
Path            SideIndicator
----            -------------
C:\test\bar.txt <=
C:\test\baz.txt =>
C:\test\foo.txt <>
```

Now we get only a single line for "foo.txt", where `<>` clearly shows that the file has been modified. I didn't output the hash values because I don't see much use for them in this output format. If you need them, add a property to the `[pscustomobject]` and assign `$_.Group.Hash`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to compare every single Hash in the CSV or just the Hash of the File?
For this you could us the `Compare-Object` cmdlet. For further Information plase provide more Information
[Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Thank you for answering i want to Compare Every single hash Inside the newly created CSV and compare with the hashes inside the Originalhashes.csv i will be more than happy if you can edit my command so it can do the compare also after generating the hashes thanks

Comment: _"...i will be more than happy if you can edit my command so it can do the compare also after generating the hashes thanks"_  SO isn't a code-writing service; you should read the referenced documentation and give it a go yourself, then post any specific questions you have.

Comment: SO is a platform for information exchange as boxdog already mentioned not a code-writing service. 
Remember from simple control c and control v you will not learn anything about coding.